# Issue with a join on MySQL 5.5.32

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Good morning everyone.
I am having some difficulties trying to get a query to work (to build a view on it afterwards)

My table structure is this (shortened for brevity)

SUBS: code, mag, start, end
USERS: code, email
ISSUES: mag, issue, pubdate

"subs" contains subscriptions to magazines: CODE is the company code, MAG is the identifier of the mag, START and END are the dates on which the subscription is valid.
"users" contains emails associated with the company codes (1/N)
"issues" is a list of each issue of each magazine, with its publication date

**SAMPLE DATA**

[This Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a31a) should provide you some sample data. Here's a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/7q3EXifv) with the create statements with sample data

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**
For each user, all the subscription he/she is entitled to, with starting issue and ending issue. Speaking with column names:
USERS.email, ISSUES.mag, SUBS.start, ISSUES.issue, SUBS.end, ISSUES.issue

For the sample data I provided this should be:
johndoe@mail.com,01ARS,2014-01-01,01ARS14000387,2014-03-01,01ARS14000389

**WHAT I HAVE SO FAR**

```
SELECT users.email, subs.mag, subs.start, subs.end
FROM users
LEFT JOIN subs ON users.code = subs.code
```

I can't get current values for the start_issue and end_issue
My, albeit limited, knowledge of sql I guess it's not enough to achieve this

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Good evening... please show us the code where you `JOIN`.

Comment: I updated the original post with what I have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.email, t3.mag, t2.start, t3.issue s, t2.end, t4.issue e
FROM users t1
JOIN subs t2 ON t1.code = t2.code
JOIN issues t3 ON t2.mag = t3.mag AND t2.start = t3.pubdate
JOIN issues t4 ON t2.mag = t4.mag AND t2.end = t4.pubdate;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9fa12/6/0)

Comment: Thank you @Mikolaj  or you answer but this is not the correct output. I probably explained myself badly. For the provided data, the correct output should be:  


`johndoe@mail.com , 01ARS , 2014-01-01 , 01ARS14000387 , 2014-03-01 , 01ARS14000389`  

`laracroft@mail.com , 01ARS , 2014-01-01 , 01ARS14000387 , 2014-03-01 , 01ARS14000389`  


The difficult part seems to be getting the first and last issue included in the subscription

Comment: thank you for tour time, this is invaluable for me to learn more. I owe you a beer.

One last question: what if the subs.end (or start) is few days over the isses.pubdate? Your current example works only if the subscriptions start on the first day of the month, which is not the case.

Honestly, you can consider just the month and year of publication to compare the dates of start/end of the subscription.

Comment: @MatteoPirelli Well, on this line `JOIN issues t4 ON t2.mag = t4.mag AND t2.end = t4.pubdate` you could instead do: `JOIN issues t4 ON t2.mag = t4.mag AND t2.end >= t4.pubdate`. You can use the `>=` or `<=` (more than or equal to, less than or equal to) to generate the outcome you are looking for.